# 404 Page Not Found error in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-server, sub-site, farm, page-not-found

I have a sub site who's home page is set to default.aspx which is not stored in any of the document library like pages,site assets or site pages.Below is the URL structure.

http://server-X:port/sites/sc/subsite/default.aspx

We have three servers in the farm and when we access server-1 and server-2 urls, this default.aspx loads fine.However when I try to access Server-3 url than I am receiving "404 page not found" error.I was able to resolve the issue by restoring the page using designer.

But My actual question is, **why default.aspx is not loading on specific server and where page is loading fine of other 2 servers?**

Please help me to understand the reason behind this problem.Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Default.aspx page is a page stored in the WFE(Web Front End) of the Sharepoint Folder. I guess for some reason the page did not copy across all WFE .

Comment: To my knowledge, Default.aspx is template where all required information will be stored in SQL DB for this specific page of site  collection or sub site .When page is requested than SharePoint will render all the info from SQL.So we were under impression that, there is some issue with SQL records.